# How to transfer a DataTable between pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a DataTable at page1.aspx and want page2.aspx to read and storage that DataTable so i can freely use this one too.

There is a simple way to do that?

It's only for a college homework so nothig too big or complicated, only a DataTable with simple items.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a Session variable

in page1 code behind

```
Session["dt1"] = dtFullGrid;
```

in page2 code behind

```
GridView1.DataSource = Session["dt1"];
GridView1.DataBind();
```

or

```
Datatable dt2 = new Datatable();
dt2 = (DataTable)Session["dt1"];
```

Answer (score 0):

@NorbertoEscobar offered good solution, but you may use Class to do that. In class you have some function, that will return datatable, or have datatable as it is.

```
DataTable dt = YourClass.GetMyDataTable();
```

Or void function:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
YourClass.FillMyDataTable(dt);
```